# Can I travel the Schengen area without my British spouse?

Tags: schengen-visas, eu-citizens

I was granted multi entry Schengen visa for 6 months, as an EU family member as my husband is British and I will be traveling mostly with him.

However I am wondering if I can travel without him, under this visa, let’s say just a weekend with my friends. Will I get in trouble?

Comment: What does your visa say?

Answer (score 5):

Generally, yes, you can use this visa without your husband, but you should be aware of some technical quirks.

The most significant of these is that you are not subject to the 90/180 rule when you are traveling with your husband (or to join him).  However, time spent in the Schengen area with him *does* count when you are figuring days of presence for a visit without him.  So you could spend a weekend in the Schengen area and then return with your husband the next week for 90 days or more, but if you spend 90 days there with him then you won't be able to go by yourself until after you've waited at least 90 days outside the Schengen area.

Another thing to keep in mind is that these rules will change when the UK stops participating in the free movement regime.  That is currently expected on December 31, 2020, but it could be postponed.  If your visa's six month validity begins in July 2020 or later, this might be relevant to you.